# Using Javascript to Display Business Hours

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I am in the process of developing a new website for a University Library.  It will include a feature to display the hours open on any given day.  A lot of libraries do this using some combination of PHP and a back-end database or Google Calendar Integration.  For a variety of reasons we cannot do that so I've opted to use Javascript as it is known to work with our CMS (WordPress) without me having to bother the campus webmaster.

My initial approach was to use several different files, each with a switch statement to display hours based on the day of the week.  We have 3 types of hours (regular, exam week, and intercession) and only one location.  Nevertheless having to swap files introduces a degree of human error.

Thus I decided to use one file.  The approach which makes most sense is to get the date, format it like month/number of week in the month (first second, third, etc)/date and use a series of if ... else statements to compare the current date to that and then run a switch statement to pick out the correct hours for the current day of the week.

Problem is the conditional in the first if statement keeps evaluating as true even when its not.  Can anybody tell me what I've done wrong?  Or is there a better approach to this task?

Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/mjcodelib/9aKmC/

```
var current = new Date();                           //creates new date object
var date = current.getDate();                       //gets date of month
var weekDay = current.getDay();                     //gets day of week 
var week_num = Math.floor((date - 1) / 7) + 1;      //determines the week in the month 
var month = current.getMonth() + 1;                 //gets month number
var date_formatted = month + '/' + week_num + '/' + weekDay;    
//puts date into    month/week number/date format
var date_month = month + '/' + date;

var date_test = new Date (2014, 11, 24);            //for troubleshooting

if (date_formatted >= '12/3/1') {                   //begin winter intercession     
    switch (weekDay)            {                   
        case 0:
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Closed Today";
            break;
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 8:00AM to    4:30PM" + date_test;
            break;
        case 5:
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 8:00AM to 4:00PM";
            break;
        case 6: 
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Closed Today";
            break;
    } 
} else if (date_formatted >= '12/2/1') {            //begin fall exam week
        switch (weekDay)                {               
            case 0:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 2:00PM to 12:00PM";
                break;
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 7:30AM to 12:00AM";
                break;
            case 5:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 7:30AM to 4:00PM";
                break;
            case 6: 
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Closed Today";
                break;
    }
} else if (date_formatted >= '11/4/1') {        //begin Thanksgiving intercession
        switch (weekDay)            {                   
            case 0:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Closed Today";
                break;
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 8:00AM to 4:30PM";
                break;
            case 5:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 8:00AM to 4:00PM";
                break;
            case 6: 
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Closed Today";
                break;
    } 
} else if (date_formatted >= '10/4/1') {        //resume regular hours after fall break
        switch (weekDay)    {                           
            case 0:
                document.getElementByID("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 2:00PM to 10:00PM";
                break;
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 7:30AM to 10:00PM";
                break;
            case 5:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 7:30AM to 4:00PM";
                break;
            case 6: 
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Closed Today";
                break;
    }
} else if (date_formatted > '10/3/3') {         //Fall break
        switch (weekDay)            {                   
            case 0:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Closed Today";
                break;
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 8:00AM to 4:30PM";
                break;
            case 5:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 8:00AM to 4:00PM";
                break;
            case 6: 
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Closed Today";
                break;
    } 
} else if (date_formatted == '10/3/3' ) {           //begin fall break
    document.getElementByID("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 7:30 AM - 5:00PM";
} else if (date_formatted >= '8/3/1') {             //begin fall semester
    switch (weekDay)    {                           
        case 0:
            document.getElementByID("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 2:00PM to 10:00PM";
            break;
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 7:30AM to 10:00PM";
            break;
        case 5:
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 7:30AM to 4:00PM";
            break;
        case 6: 
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Closed Today";
            break;
    }
} else if (date_month >= '8/1') {               //begin August intercession
    switch (weekDay)            {                   
        case 0:
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Closed Today";
            break;
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 8:00AM to 4:30PM";
            break;
        case 5:
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 8:00AM to 4:00PM";
            break;
        case 6: 
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Closed Today";
            break;
    } 
} else if (date_formatted >= '6/1/1') {         //begin regular hours for summer    
    switch (weekDay)    {                           
        case 0:
            document.getElementByID("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 2:00PM to 10:00PM";
            break;
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 7:30AM to 10:00PM";
            break;
        case 5:
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 7:30AM to 4:00PM";
            break;
        case 6: 
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Closed Today";
            break;
    }
} else if (date_formatted >= '5/2/1') {         //begin May intercession
    switch (weekDay)            {                   
        case 0:
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Closed Today";
            break;
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 8:00AM to 4:30PM";
            break;
        case 5:
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 8:00AM to 4:00PM";
            break;
        case 6: 
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Closed Today";
            break;
    } 
} else if (date_formatted >= '5/1/1') {         //begin Spring exam week
        switch (weekDay)                {               
            case 0:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 2:00PM to 12:00PM";
                break;
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 7:30AM to 12:00AM";
                break;
            case 5:
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 7:30AM to 4:00PM";
                break;
            case 6: 
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Closed Today";
                break;
    }
} else if (date_formatted >= '3/3/1') {         //resume regular hours after Spring Break 
        switch (weekDay)    {                           
        case 0:
            document.getElementByID("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 2:00PM to 10:00PM";
            break;
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 7:30AM to 10:00PM";
            break;
        case 5:
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 7:30AM to 4:00PM";
            break;
        case 6: 
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Closed Today";
            break;
    }
} else if (date_formatted >= '3/2/1') {         //begin Spring Break
    switch (weekDay)            {                   
        case 0:
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Closed Today";
            break;
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 8:00AM to 4:30PM";
            break;
        case 5:
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 8:00AM to 4:00PM";
            break;
        case 6: 
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Closed Today";
            break;
    } 
} else if (date_formatted >= '1/2/1') {         //begin Spring semester
    switch (weekDay)    {                           
        case 0:
            document.getElementByID("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 2:00PM to 10:00PM";
            break;
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 7:30AM to 10:00PM";
            break;
        case 5:
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 7:30AM to 4:00PM";
            break;
        case 6: 
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Closed Today";
            break;
    }
} else if (date_formatted >= '1/1/4') {         //Winter intercession
    switch (weekDay)            {                   
        case 0:
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Closed Today";
            break;
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 8:00AM to   4:30PM";
            break;
        case 5:
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Today's Hours: 8:00AM to 4:00PM";
            break;
        case 6: 
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML="Closed Today";
            break;
    } 
} else {
    document.getElementByID("hours").innerHTML="<a           href='http://www.deltastate.edu/academics/libraries/libraries-hours-of-operation/' target='_blank'>Click here for Library hours</a>";
}
```

Comment: Well, you're comparing strings, not dates...

Comment: You should be doing your comparisons with date objects or numbers. Don't do any comparisons with formatted date strings.

Comment: date_formatted >= '12/3/1' doesn't not a right approach to date comparison, it is only a string comparison

Comment: So it would be better to create date objects for each of the dates I wish to compare to today?

Comment: Another thing I'd suggest (just to clean up the code a bit) would be to assign `document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML` to a variable, such as `var hours`, for faster reference.

Comment: absolutely, take a look to this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate and all setxxx methods, you have to compare 2 instance of date object, the rest for the moment is sugar :)

Comment: then try to prepare a http://jsfiddle.net/ you will get more help for sure ;)

Comment: Can those dates be assigned to an array?  The reason I chose the approach above is that the important dates in our calendar vary every year but typically occur around the same time (i.e. second week in January, 3rd week in March, etc).  Comparing specific dates means they must be changed from year to year.

Comment: You're violating DRY principle - and doing it **very wrong**. A professional developer will never solve a problem this way

Comment: Neither would I under ideal circumstances.  In fact there was a PHP script I was hoping to use for the task.  However a combination of institutional politics and our infrastructure (WordPress CMS managed by the University Marketing Department) has forced me to take an unorthodox approach.  Yes its a mess, but this is the best way to accomplish things.  At the very least I am learning valuable lessons in programming and web development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A note, since I was feeling lazy and didn't want to have to figure out the calendar dates of your `month/week_num/weekDay` strings, I just implemented straight numeric comparison, and so it isn't the most efficient (or the easiest to read)

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9aKmC/2/)

Pretty much what I ended up doing was replacing every single

```
if (date_formatted >= '##/#/#')
```

with

```
if (month >= ## && week_num >= # && weekDay >= #)
```

I also added a div#hours to the jsfiddle so that you can actually see the results with different test dates and cast `document.getElementById("hours")` to a variable for readability's sake.

Comment: Thank you very much! The month/week_num/weekDay format came from a script I found on the Javascript Cookbook forum to determine if a day is a federal holiday.  Perhaps not the best source of inpirations. The thought occurred to me that I can probably use functions to compare the dates and determine which type of hours (regular, exam, or intercession) should be set.  But for now this will do.